# How to explain discrepancies between contrast estimates and mean differences?

Tags: r, regression, mean, model, lsmeans

(I'm working with R but the core of my question is about statistics.)

I'm using a quasibinomial model in R with a dependent variable and several independent variables (both numeric and dummy variables). I've used `Anova(mymodel)` from the *car* package to test which independent variable affect my dependent variable. One of these variables is a dummy variable (let's call it `dummy1`), so I computed post-hoc contrasts with `emmeans` : `emmeans(my model, specs = pairwise ~ dummy1, nuisance="otherdummyvariable")$contrasts`, which output is:

```
contrast                estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 1 - 2                  0.12587 0.407 Inf   0.309  0.9980
 1 - 3                 -0.14955 0.399 Inf  -0.375  0.9958
 1 - 4                 -0.38213 0.396 Inf  -0.964  0.8711
 1 - 5                 -0.39202 0.396 Inf  -0.989  0.8604
 2 - 3                 -0.27542 0.153 Inf  -1.798  0.3748
 2 - 4                 -0.50799 0.152 Inf  -3.337  0.0075
 2 - 5                 -0.51789 0.177 Inf  -2.925  0.0285
 3 - 4                 -0.23258 0.146 Inf  -1.594  0.5014
 3 - 5                 -0.24247 0.162 Inf  -1.501  0.5621
 4 - 5                 -0.00989 0.152 Inf  -0.065  1.0000
```

I also plotted the mean and 95%IC of each category of *dummy1* :
[here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT2gt.png)

**The thing is, as you can see, that the mean of 1 is lower than the mean of 2 but emmeans contrast 1 - 2 gives a positive estimate, same problem with the contrast 2 - 5, etc.**

**Is this usual? Am I missing something?** (I am new to both emmeans and quasibinomial regressions).

I would expect a positive estimate in the case of a positive difference of means and a negative estimates in the case of a negative difference of means.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on here, but the documentation recommends using the `contrast` function to get contrasts:

> Note: contr is ignored when specs is a formula. Note 2:: We recommend
> against using this argument; obtaining means and obtaining contrasts
> are two different things, and it is best to do them in separate steps,
> using the contrast function for the contrasts.

Comment: I drew the plot from raw data (mean and 95% IC). Might the discrepancy comes from the fact that there are several variables in the model that are controlled for, while the plot of means from raw data does not control for these variables?

Comment: That could definitely do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!